# How to pass data when we have data in multi dimensional array in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I am trying to pass data to my view but I have data in multi-dimensional array.

I can iterate through it but I think using multiple `foreach` is not a good way because I have to use `foreach` loops for every single array to iterate through it.

Is there any alternative cleaner way?

Controller method code

```
public function city(city $job_test)
{
    $data = privatejobcity::where('city_id', $job_test->id)->get();

    $private_job = [];
    foreach ($data as $values) {
        echo "<pre>";
        $private_job[] = private_jobadb::with('cities')->where('id', $values->private_jobabd_id)->get();
    }

    foreach ($private_job as $values1) {
        echo "<pre>";
        echo $values1;
    }

    die();
    return view('frontend.jobTestCatagory.jobsByCities', compact('private_job'));
```

Results before `die()`

```
[{"id":31,"company_logo":null,"company_name":null,"job_desc":null,"company_phone":null,"sector_id":null,"company_eail":null,"created_at":"2017-09-03 04:38:50","updated_at":"2017-09-03 04:38:50","image":"public\/newpaper_jobs\/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAaHAAAAJDhmMTBjZmJlLWUxNmQtNDE3Zi1iY2Y5LTY1OWI1MzkwNzQ1YQ.png","contact_person":null,"job_title":null,"slug":null,"meta_tags":null,"meta_description":null,"cities":[{"id":4,"city_name":"Islamabad","pivot":{"private_jobabd_id":31,"city_id":4}}]}]
[{"id":32,"company_logo":null,"company_name":null,"job_desc":null,"company_phone":null,"sector_id":null,"company_eail":null,"created_at":"2017-09-03 04:44:09","updated_at":"2017-09-03 04:44:09","image":null,"contact_person":null,"job_title":null,"slug":null,"meta_tags":null,"meta_description":null,"cities":[{"id":4,"city_name":"Islamabad","pivot":{"private_jobabd_id":32,"city_id":4}}]}]
[{"id":33,"company_logo":null,"company_name":null,"job_desc":null,"company_phone":null,"sector_id":null,"company_eail":null,"created_at":"2017-09-03 04:50:28","updated_at":"2017-09-03 04:50:28","image":"public\/newpaper_jobs\/241_District-Council-Bahawalnagar.jpg","contact_person":null,"job_title":null,"slug":null,"meta_tags":null,"meta_description":null,"cities":[{"id":4,"city_name":"Islamabad","pivot":{"private_jobabd_id":33,"city_id":4}}]}]
[{"id":46,"company_logo":null,"company_name":null,"job_desc":null,"company_phone":null,"sector_id":1,"company_eail":null,"created_at":"2017-09-03 06:53:46","updated_at":"2017-09-03 06:53:46","image":null,"contact_person":null,"job_title":null,"slug":"943","meta_tags":null,"meta_description":null,"cities":[{"id":4,"city_name":"Islamabad","pivot":{"private_jobabd_id":46,"city_id":4}},{"id":3,"city_name":"Karachi","pivot":{"private_jobabd_id":46,"city_id":3}}]}]
```

Comment: Join `privatejobcity` with `private_jobadb` and pass you multidimensional array to you view is fine for you. And then iterate array in your view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know it will work or not. but you can use join something like this.

```
$result = privatejobcity::join(
        'private_jobadb', 
        'privatejobcity.private_jobabd_id',  '=', 'private_jobadb.id'
    )->with('cities')
    ->where('privatejobcity.city_id', $job_test->id)
    ->get();
```

If you post your table details then we can answer easily to your question.